# Cannot get CORS working within MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I've got a pretty simple request set up to test CORS is working, as follows:

```
$.get( "http://www.otherdomain.com/thecontroller/test", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I've even tried a vanilla javascript CORS request via the following..

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.otherdomain.com/thecontroller/test');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        console.log('response: ' + this.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

However these keeps getting the CORS error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource) in both FF and Chrome.

On the server side I've tried quite a few things but for now just to test that I can get it working I'm allowing all CORS requests to the action, ie..

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    //stuff
}
```

Am I missing something?  Does Chrome / Firefox cache OPTIONS request?  When I examine the network traffic in developer tools it only seems to be performing the GET method (and cancelling due to CORS) but it doesn't list any OPTIONS method.

I've even put a breakpoint in the Global.asax to try and catch the request, but it isn't even hitting it ie..

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss now, any ideas?

Comment: In order to force the OPTIONS pre-flight, try adding a custom header to your ajax request because a plain GET request doesn't require an OPTIONS pre-flight check. At least it might help to debug the issue...Also, check to make sure that your request is sending the "Origin" header - the browser might for some reason think that this is not a CORS request and omit the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment under my question, it turns out that I had to add a custom header to the jquery axax request.  This forced the browser to send the OPTIONS request.  This seems a bit hacky to me but it works, here is the solution:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.otherdomain.com/thecontroller/test',
    headers: {
        'MyCustomHeader': 'important information'
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('failure');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thing you may try (caveat: I'm kinda green on this stuff, too)...

Did you enable CORS in your application Config class?

```
...
// Enable Cors
config.EnableCors();
...
```

Also, I think you're supposed to add the EnableCors[...] decorator on the controller, not the Action. At least that's how I've always done it.

```
namespace Your_API.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class YourController : ApiController
    {
```

For reference: [This is a pretty solid walk-through I used in the past to get my own project going](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: This is on a standard controller, not an ApiController, I know, not the best practice but it's required in this case.  I have enabled CORS and I've seen it working in the past on the action rather than the whole controller.  I however think something is up client side as it simply isn't firing the OPTIONS request, so it basically isn't even asking my application if it will accept the request